Division , is it the quantity contained by one group?
Disclaimer: This might sound stupid
Division means dividing something into groups, that is how most people define division.
So by definition it is how much of the number belongs to a single group when it is divided into $n$ groups.
Example:
$10/2 = 5$ which means
$10$ can be split into $2$ groups and each group has a quantity of $5.$
Division also means the number of times $2$ can fit in $10,$ basically $2$ multiplied by what number is gonna give you $10$ as the result.
In both cases the value is $5.$ But the first definition of division varies from the second definition. How does the first definition equal the second definition? ie ,if the values are the same then there is something that I am missing which is stopping me from considering both these definitions the same.

Division is the inverse of multiplication. These are concepts you should have learned before having access to a computer.

Even if we can't get this deleted, this question has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Why do you pick random tags you don't know the meaning of?

If I'm understanding this correctly, you are heuristically defining $\frac{m}{n}$ in the following way: it's that number $x$ such that if you wanted to give an equal portion of $m$ to $n$ different people, you'd give them $x$. Directly by this "definition", if you were to sum $x$ with itself $n$ times, you'd be getting back $m$ (because you divided $m$ in $n$ portions each of which "weighs" x). This means that the number of times $n$ can fit into $m$ is $x$. Conversely, define $\frac{m}{n}$ as the number of times $x$ you can fit $n$ into $m$ and let's say you now want to distribute $m$ equally among $n$ different people. By definition, $x$ is the number of times you can fit $n$ into $m$. This means that if you were to ditribute exactly $x$ to each person, you'd be distributing $m$ equally among your $n$ friends. I don't know how much of this makes sense since it's all very not formal, but it was funny thinking about it.

This is exactly what I was looking for. This question might sound really stupid since one is just implied from the other. But I was really looking for proof on paper which is exactly what you gave. This question could easily be mistaken for why mn = nm but that is not the question. Thanks man!
